# The professor's mouthful

Tags: language

"I beg your pardon?" I spluttered. "You study what?! That sounds like a tongue-twister."

She repeated it, and I asked what it meant.

"I study the cause of the naming conventions of insects."

What were her three fields of study?

Comment: Far too easy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The professors mouthful must have been some working of the three fields:

> Etiology (study of causes or origins);
>  Entomology (study of insects); and
>  Etymology (study of word origins)

Maybe

> Etioentomonetyology?

Comment: As mentioned in [XKCD 1012](https://xkcd.com/1012/).

Comment: You're an enigmatologist and a scholar